# CSS selector for asp.net checkbox

Tags: asp.net, css, checkbox, css-selectors

What is the correct CSS selector for ASP.net checkboxes?

I tried `input[type="checkbox"] + label` , `input[type="checkbox"]` and `input` itself but none can select the checkbox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ASP.NET `CheckBox` control produces HTML with `input` tag with type `checkbox`, so there should be no problem with standard CSS selectors.

I have copied a HTML produced by [W3Schools example of using `CheckBox` control](http://www.w3schools.com/aspnet/showaspx.asp?filename=demo_checkbox) and tried `input[type="checkbox"] + label` selector and it worked - check [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fELEY/).

With this being said, I think your problem is somewhere else and you should carefully check yout code.

Comment: W3Schools is not W3C. Please don't get the two mixed up.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need the quotes in the type argument.

To get the checkbox itself,

```
input[type=checkbox]
```

To get the label text,

```
input[type=checkbox] + label
```

Comment: You don't need them, but that doesn't mean you can't have them there.